# Parsing a non regular text file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to parse a text file that looks like this using pandas:

```
Some random text
more random text that may be of different length
JUNK 0 9 8
GOOD 0 1 1
GOOD 5 5 5
more random text interdispersed
GOOD 123 321 2
JUNK 55 1 9
GOOD 1 2 3
```

The file is space delimited.
I only care about lines that start with 'GOOD', which will all have the same formatting.

I believe that `read_table()` is the right command but I don't know how to filter it.

My current method of parsing files is to open the file, use regex to match the lines I care about and then split the line on spaces.  This can be slow and I am looking for a faster cleaner way.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need regex to match lines that start with "GOOD".  Just iterate over the file and throw away all other lines, creating a "clean" copy of the data you want:

```
with open('irregular.txt') as inFile, open('regular.txt', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in inFile:
        if line.startswith('GOOD'):
            outFile.write(line)
```

Then you can read "regular.txt" using `read_table` or `read_csv` with the `delim_whitespace=True` argument.

Comment: This is going to be a big speed problem because I open thousands of files in a directory with tens of thousands of files.  I want to avoid intermediary writing and reading if at all possible.  I am tempted to think that my current implementation is faster than this.

Comment: If you're going to read tens of thousands of files, the fastest thing you can do is preprocess each file once and transform it to a regular format that you can easily read.  Trying to actually parse the irregular file every time is less efficient than trying to convert it to an efficiently-readable form.

Answer (score 2):

Lets make a generator that filters good lines

```
def generate_good_lines(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        if line.startswith('GOOD'):
            yield line
```

Now all you need is parse these lines in way you want, eg:

```
def generate_parsed(filename_list):
    for filename in filename_list:
        for line in generate_good_lines(filename)
            data = your_parser_function(line)
            yield data
```

Then you consume all lines into list (for example):

```
your_list = list(generate_parsed(your_filename_list))
```

in your question it looks like your_parser_function looks like this:

```
def your_parser_function(line):
    return map(int, line[5:].split()) # split values and convert them to integers
```

generators take care about your memory and processor time consumption

/ sorry for my english /